# Node.js wait for multiple events

Tags: node.js, event-handling, dom-events

How to wait in a clean way for multiple events to be emitted ?

Something like:

```
event.on(['db:mongo:ready', 'db:redis:ready', 'db:rethinkdb:ready'], function() {
   server.listen()
});
```

Comment: have you looked into promises?

Comment: No but will I be able to event.emit('something') ?

Comment: yes, you can. my understanding was that you want to know when all events are fired.

Answer (score 6):

Just use `Promise.all` to wait for all events to be ready.

**Example wait multiple connection with** [mongoose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose):

```
const mongoose1 = require("mongoose");
const mongoose2 = require("mongoose");

const dbUrl1 = "mongodb://localhost:27017/db1";
const dbUrl2 = "mongodb://localhost:27017/db2";

mongoose1.connect(dbUrl1);
mongoose2.connect(dbUrl2);

const allDb = [mongoose1, mongoose2];

function waitEvent(event) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    event.on("connected", resolve);
    event.on("error", reject);
  });
}

async function prepareAllDb() {
  let pendingProcess = [];

  allDb.forEach(database => {
    // mongoose put their event on mongoose.connection
    pendingProcess.push(waitEvent(database.connection));
  });

  await Promise.all(pendingProcess);
}

prepareAllDb().then(() => {
  console.log("All databases are ready to use");

  // Run your server in here
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This example is done using [rsvp](https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js/) promises:

```
var RSVP = require('rsvp'),
    Promise = RSVP.Promise;

var emitted_promises = [];


yourEvents.foreach(function(eventName){
  emitted_promises.push(new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    event.on(eventName, function(){
      resolve('done');
    });
  });
});

RSVP.all(emitted_promises)
  .then(function(emitted){
      //now you know they all are done
      emitted; //array of 'done' but can be passed anything you need
  });
```